# Working with image pixels

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to do a project here, which I want to implement the following:

I have a rotation matrix and translation matrix are estimated, now I have an image in a certain location and I want to multiply all the image pixel by the rotation matrix and add the results to the translation matrix.....

My issue is how to work with the pixels? I mean how to extract the pixel from the image in order to do the operation that I mentioned above?

it's ok to give me the suggestion in either opencv or c++

***I need to know how to do this operation 
new_p(x,y) = old_p(x,y)* rotation_matrix + translation_matrix.
I'm defining the image like that IplImage(), 3 channel image. 
For now I need to do the geometrical transformation but I don't know how to use old_p(x,y) which mean old pixels***

Thank you.

Comment: This depends upon your implementation of 'Image'.  Is it a raw array of color values, a hand-rolled image class, or using some kind of image loading library such as FreeImage?

Comment: I didn't get your point here exactly, but I will tell you what I'm doing. I'm working on video and I want to return the second image that I get to the previous location, i.e the location of the first frame.

Comment: The point is that the answer is going to be wholly dependent on how you are handling these images.  As it stands it cannot be answered.  There are no image classes in C++.  You could be talking about an array of bytes or some library "Image" class for all we know.

Answer (score 4):

In Opencv, the functions you need are in the "Geometric Image transformations" section of the manual. In your case, as you already have the rotation matrix and the translation, `warpAffine` is the function of choice ([link to function documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_geometric_image_transformations.html)). First two columns of the transformation matrix that you pass are the rotation matrix, the third is the translation vector (in case you are not familiar with homogeneous coordinates).

Comment: the answer still stands. `warpAffine`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea will be that you need a color value for every pixel in the final result image. So you need to find a function which maps a (rotated and translated) pixel onto every `(x,y)` position of the final result image.

Given a matrix transforming the original image coordinates to target image coordinates, you'll probably end up inverting that transformation and applying that for every target image pixel, plus or minus a few optimizations.

Comment: For the first part of your answer; yeah right that's what I need and my question is which functions to use and how?
for the second part, I'm working on translating the image location to its previous location

Comment: And like we have already said, it depends on how you are manipulating these images.  C++ does not contain anything related to image manipulation in the standard library.  Either you are reading an image into an array or you are using some third party API.  We can't give you an answer without more information.

Comment: I can give you even the code if you want and any more information you are interest in. 
I'm using opencv which is a library to manipulate the image.