# Pixel coordinates opencv, c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to know how to extract all pixels locations for the frame and put them in a matrix in order to make some operations on them. 2D frames, so it will be (x,y) coordinates.

I Have obtained a rotation matrix and translation matrices of features between 2 frames in captured video, now I wanna use these matrices to multiply it by the image in order to correct the video frames

I prefer to use opencv functions.

Comment: All image pixels are on a grid. Do you mean any particular pixels?

Comment: I Have obtained a rotation matrix and translation matrices of features  between 2 frames in captured video, now I wanna use these matrices to multiply it by the image in order to correct the video frames

Comment: Do you want to transform your whole frame according to the rotation and translation matrix? Is that your question?

Comment: yeah exactly, show me how please. 
i need it so urgent

Comment: I don't have moderator access, but he already asked this question a day ago on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673799/working-with-image-pixels, so this one should be closed.

Comment: yeah, but the same problem and it is not solved

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply the transformation to the whole image to create a warped image. There is no need to do this on a pixel list.
You should use [cvWarpAffine()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/geometric_image_transformations.html#cvWarpAffine) with your matrix to get the warped image.

Comment: Yeah, but I have 3*3 matrix. I'm not interested in warp affine.

Comment: A rotation matrix in 2 dimensions is a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: yeah right sorry about the mistake but still I can't use it in that function, cause it need 2*3 matrix

Comment: And I told you in the answer to your old question how to get the 2x3 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient direct pixel access in openCV http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/faq#Howtoaccessimagepixels

Comment: this is outdated C api. he asked for C++.

Comment: The layout of the images hasn't changed.